# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

Tags: python, json, type-error, google-translate

я хочу перевести несколько переменных сразу на русский язык, но мне выдает ошибку

вот код:

```py
# переменные для перевода
successful_registration = 'successful registration!'
the_username_is_already_in_use = 'the username is already in use!'
invalid_user_name = 'invalid user name!'
successful_login = 'successful login!'
invalid_password = 'invalid password!'

# функция перевода
def lang(lang):
    # создание объекта переводчика
    translator = Translator()
    # список переводимых переменных
    variables = (successful_registration, the_username_is_already_in_use, invalid_user_name, successful_login, invalid_password)
    # перевод каждой переменной и замена ее значения на переведенное
    for i in range(len(variables)):
       [i] = translator.translate(variables[i], dest=lang).text
    # возвращаем обновленные переменные
    return tuple(translator.translate(var, dest=lang).text for var in variables)

# обновляемные для перевода на английский язык
successful_registration, the_username_is_already_in_use, invalid_user_name, successful_login, invalid_password = lang('ru')
```

вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Имя\Desktop\!PYTHON`s\main project\dist.main.py", line 31, in <module>
    successful_registration, the_username_is_already_in_use, invalid_user_name, successful_login, invalid_password = lang('ru')
                                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Имя\Desktop\!PYTHON`s\main project\dist.main.py", line 26, in lang
    [i] = translator.translate(variables[i], dest=lang).text
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Имя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 219, in translate
    parsed = json.loads(data[0][2])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Имя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

в чем может быть проблема и как её можно решить?

Comment: Точно такая же проблема. Причем у меня код иногда работает по 10+ раз, иногда отваливается сразу. Вам удалось решить проблему? Наверное придется использовать другой API

Comment: нет, я проверил на другом файле с менее большим содержанием. в случае 1/5 он работал а все остальные случаи нет